# how to pass querystring in friendly url in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

Hope this is the best place to put this question.
I am working on a web application.Where any user can check detail of other user by a link.
currently this is the link for test

http://www.contractgenies.com/Snapshotprofile.aspx?ViewRef=test09last099826

it is working fine but

**Problem :**

I want to show this as :

http://www.contractgenies.com/test09last099826

without query string or page name.

**Is this possible or not please let me know.**

Comment: Please change the title and the question in a clear question that can be answered.

Comment: Please advise me a question name for this.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is called **URL Rewriting**. Check [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) on how to do URL rewriting on ASP .NET

Comment: @RanhiruCooray this technology is VERY OLD. (2007). nowdays - we use routing.

Comment: If you can't think of a good title, you probably don't know what the question is either.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I disagree. he just need the right term.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I only knew that it was called as such. The above link came up with a simple Google search. Please suggest the latest way of URL Rewriting on ASP .NET to Sunny :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I am not asking for the correct term, I just think that "How can I do this" is never a good title as it covers 99% of all questions here.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Agreed. ( silly argument though :-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use UrlRewriting mechanism to achieve this job.

[URL Rewriting Module](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

If you are going to use ASP.Net MVC then use routing mechanism.

[Routing Mechanism ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: Routing can be used also with web-form. not only with mvc. it sounds like (from your answer) that routing is only for mvc. p.s. +1.

Comment: Yep, use routing, it's more powerful and more flexible

Comment: @RoyiNamir how we can use with web form ?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx gives an example of use with webforms

Comment: @sohail I am looking into these links i will update you asap.

Comment: Thanks for @Basic,@sohail and all for providing their help.